# Error in populating Datagrid view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, hebrew

I have a database which contains Hebrew language(foreign characters) in it.

When I populate it in grid view.

It gets populated in reverse order(left to right)

For example: "כן" is getting populated as "ןכ"

Can i get Help??

Comment: To be clear,
I have a access database that contains foreign characters(Hebrew Language).
Hebrew language is a Right To Left language

When i populate it using OledbDataAdapter..
The value gets populated reversely..

(i.e) "אין" is getting populated as "ןיא".

Can Anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

**Set the `DataGridView` control's [`RightToLeft` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) to `RightToLeft.Yes`.** This instructs the control that it should align itself to support locales that use right-to-left fonts (such as Hebrew).

The documentation is pretty explicit here:

> The RightToLeft property is used for international applications where the language is written from right to left, such as Hebrew or Arabic. When this property is set to RightToLeft.Yes, control elements that include text are displayed from right to left.

You can do this either in the Visual Studio designer, or through code like so:

```
myDataGridView.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Comment: No, i think you have misunderstood my question, I too have come across right to left property in grid view.                                                             My question is when the grid view populates data from access it reads the data from right to left and populates it in grid view in as left to right.(i mean it collapes the data)                                  "כן" is getting populated as "ןכ"